# Where is the camera button in the Google Image Search webpage on my Android?

Tags: camera, google-search

Device: Samsung Galaxy S3
OS: 4.1.1

I want to do a reverse image search on my S3 phone. When I open up the Google Image Search homepage, the "camera" button is nowhere to be found. So, I cannot upload a photo.  I opened the page in Chrome, and the stock browser but I still don't see it.

How can I do a reverse image search from my phone?

Answer (score 8):

Best option is to request the desktop website on your Google Chrome browser.

1. Tap the menu button of your browser.
2. Tick the check box next to `Desktop Site`.
3. Now go to the [Google Images](https://google.com/imghp) website (google.com/imghp).

And you have the look and feel of the website like you'd expect it on your computer.

Comment: Works in Chrome on my Note 4.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried using [Google Goggles](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.unveil) instead? This is Google's app for doing a reverse image search using a camera. Make sure to enable `Search from Camera`.

You can also use an existing picture in your gallery. Open settings (circle button at lower right), then click the icon that looks like a mountain with an arrow (2nd button from left).

Comment: I have it but I want to use a picture saved on my phone.

Comment: @verve See my edit (2nd paragraph). If it works, don't forget to upvote and accept answer. :)

Comment: Google goggles won't actually accept an image with no text nor barcode.

Answer (score 1):

Google seems to block some webbrowsers/versions from search with image.

if you change useragent string in your browser settings to Firefox/4 (or anything more than 3) google show you the camera-icon so you can search with a image again like was possible before.

(firefox have this setting under general.useragent.extra.firefox in about:config
your phones browser might have it somewhere else)

Answer (score 0):

I just found the alternative solution using [Search by image](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.searchbyimage.app) app. This app lets me search by image on my smartphone. I can upload my photos to search via Google easily. You can also share images from any website to social media in one click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Desktop Mode in your browser, in order to see the camera icon.

Answer (score 0):

Just open Google Chrome on your phone. Then select 3 dots on top right corner and put a tick mark at " **Desktop Mode** ". Then go to Google Images as usual, there will be a camera button